# Hide or Show if Current, jQuery

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have this list:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="dl-nav-1 current"><a href="#">Spring Training 2001</a><span class="visible"><img src="img/indicator.png" alt="" /></li>
    <li class="dl-nav-2"><a href="#">NFL 2011</a><span class="hidden"><img src="img/indicator.png" alt="" /></span></li>
    <li class="dl-nav-3"><a href="#">Fantasy Baseball</a><span class="hidden"><img src="img/indicator.png" alt="" /></span></li>
</ul>
```

I need to show the `<span>` when the li class is current, and hide the `<span>` when it is not current.

There is a JS plugin that will change the li class, so when it changes to current, make `<span>` visible and when it removes current, hide `<span>`

terrible attempt:

```
$(function) () {
    if($(ul.pagination li).hasClass("current")) {
        $("ul.pagination li.current span").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
    } 
    else{
        $("ul.pagination li.current span").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible")
    }

};
```

Comment: Can you correct your question, it is missing words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need javascript to do the toggling of classes, CSS can do the rest:

```
ul.pagination li.current span {
    display:inline;
}

ul.pagination li span {
    display:none;   
}
```

Then, using Justin808's example, you'd do something like this for the javascript:

```
function ToggleIndicator(liClass) {
    $('.'+liClass).toggleClass('current');
}

$('#clickme').click(function() { ToggleIndicator('dl-nav-3');});
```

Forking Justin808's jsfiddle, you get this:  http://jsfiddle.net/uwTEZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can easily add/remove this class from element like so:

```
$('.dl-nav-1').find('span').addClass('visible');
$('.dl-nav-2').find('span').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
```

Easier way to reset all list items, before setting one to current:

```
$('.pagination').children().find('span').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
```

Comment: addClass and removeClass (lowercase)

Comment: Yes, but it the class needs to be shown only when li class= current, and removed if not...

Comment: Oops, Guillaume86 is correct - updated answer to reflect this. 
Xtian, I believe you have enough to go on.  If you need to check if another elements has a certain class applied to it first, then use this:  http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/m7NZ4/) is an example that will hide and show based on your classes. Any time you change your classes, call the 'UpdateIndicators' function.

*Update*:

If you want to update the indicators via javascript, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m7NZ4/1/) is an example with a toggle function.

Answer (score 0):

To get the 'current' li:

li[class$=current]

http://weblogs.asp.net/stevewellens/archive/2011/02/13/jquery-selector-tester-and-cheat-sheet.aspx